# Isotope with angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-isotope, observable

How can i use isotope jquety lib with angular2 and observables. When I get data from server i want to apply isotope. For now I have:

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {Heroes} from "./heroes";
import {ApiclientService} from "./apiclient.service";

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'heroes-list.html',
    providers: [ApiclientService]
})

export class HeroesComponent {

    public Heroes: Heroes[] = [];

    constructor(private _apiclientService: ApiclientService) {
        this.getHeroes();
    }

    getHeroes() {
        this._apiclientService.getHeroes()
                 .subscribe(
                    heroes => this.heroes = heroes,
                    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);


    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.heroes-grid').isotope({
                itemSelector: '.heroes-item'
            });
        });
    }
}
```

This doesnt work because jquery is resolved before observable subscribe method is returning some data. If i call isotope after observable is resolved, also with no success. What is the best way to approach to this kind of situations. How to combine jquery plugins and observables?

Answer (score 0):

In case you're still stuck on this, one problem could be that you need to bind the isotope initialization to the window onLoad event instead of document onready to make sure that all of the images have been loaded.

Also, in the heroes service subscribe handler, you likely need to call the isotope insert method in order to make the isotope container aware of the new elements:

```
var newItems = $('.blog-masonry-item');
$('.blog-masonry-container').isotope('insert', newItems);
```